# non-JS module files deprecated. crbug/1173575

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Okay so I recently started a Udemy course. I got a pre-coded HTML file, when I run it creates a launch.json file. Once the JSON file comes in, it won't run anymore and displays the error in the title. In the JSON file there's a port that's 8080 if that helps at all. After a lot of tries to fix this, somehow I created a JSON file without the "port" but with a "file" that navigates to the HTML file that works just fine.

Comment: Do any [of the other question about that error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crbug%2F1173575) help? Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried, what your setup is, etc. See [ask] and [mre] for more pointers on what is needed for good answers to question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.